# Is there a way to speed up the canvas.toDatalessJSON() function to save the history of the canvas?

Tags: javascript, optimization, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabric.js in my project and I have to render 10000+ items with lot of custom variables. I tried to optimize the performance with the info from this page https://github.com/kangax/fabric.js/wiki/Optimizing-performance but still its taking lot of time.

We have undo, redo, zoom and edit features in our project so I am using JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON()); for storing the details. Its working completely fine until the no of objects are less than 7000.. Is there any way to simplify the JSON function?

Here is the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r0zrpbqs/

```
function updateModifications(savehistory) {
    if (savehistory === true) {
        myjson = JSON.stringify(canvas.toDatalessJSON());
        //console.log(myjson);
        chk = chk + 1;
        state.push(myjson);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try just `JSON.stringify(canvas)`. Presumably `toDatalessJSON()` is optimized for minimal output size, not speed of execution.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @Matt Ball.. I tried it but it still taking a long time.. Is there any way to stringify parts by parts like first 1000 items and next another 1000 etc? I really appreciate any help.. Thanks